# Retrieve values from the array containing multiple objects from API in react?

Tags: reactjs, api

I am using fetch method to retrieve data from the API in my react app using the code written below.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let auth_token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let header_obj = {"x-access-token": auth_token};
    fetch('http://example.com/xyz', {headers: header_obj})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        postData:response.data  //initially set to an empty array in constructor
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

This works fine. It gives me the exact response i.e. an array containing multiple objects which is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "title": "John Doe",
        "description": "Active User",
        "dates": "4th Jan 2018"
    },
    {....} //multiple objects
  ]
 }
```

Now when I try to access any object from the response, like

```
render() {
  const {postData} = this.state;
  return (
      <div>       
         <h1>{postData[0].username}</h1> 
      </div>
    )
 }
```

This gave me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens probably because before the response has arrived the `postData` is empty array, hence `postData[0]` is undefined. Hence your error.

For that specific case you could try something like:

```
 <h1>{postData[0] && postData[0].username}</h1>
```

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the case when postData is not available yet, usually you can show a loader.
the if condition depends on how you started your state, in my answer I am assuming you have started postData as null

```
render() {
      const {postData} = this.state;
      if (!postData) {
         return (<div>Loading...</div>
      }
      return (
          <div>       
             <h1>{postData[0].username}</h1> 
          </div>
        )
     }
```

Comment: @VinaySingh because he assumed postData was set to null in your constructor which is not the case.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for sharing this to me.